# Better game performance in Fortnite on Windows 8.1 vs Windows 10?

Tags: hardware, windows-10, fortnite-battle-royale, windows-8.1

I have noticed a strange issue when playing Fortnite on different Operating Systems with the same hardware.

With Windows 10 installed, my CPU load is 100%, the gameplay is sluggish and suffers from input lag. But if I play on Windows 8.1, I lose input delay and in general the game becomes **much** more stable, only reaching 100% CPU utilization occasionally.

I noticed that Windows 8.1 displays 4.36 GHz in the task manager instead of 4.4 GHz, and Windows 10 displays 4.39 GHz. I believe that Windows 8.1 reserved a part of the frequency, and because of this, the processor does not overload and I can get better responsiveness.

How can I repeat the same thing in Windows 10? I tried the instructions on the following site: [How to Change Maximum Processor Frequency in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/95574-change-maximum-processor-frequency-windows-10-a.html), but it only allows regulation below 3.3 GHz, and also if I set the max processor state to 99%, it resets frequencies to 3.3 GHz.

Any ideas?

2500k@4.4Ghz

Comment: Are you using the same hardware and dual booting? Are they two separate machines? Is the OS clean install using the same set of drivers? Most of the issues are probably software related, such as drivers, incompatible software, lots of background processes running, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you get better usage in Windows 8.1 just becouse it uses your cpu less for background-operation, but maybe its because you had some software installed in Windows 10 that was sucking some usage. I suggest you to try a fresh W10 install. Anyway, Windows can reserve part of the usage, but not part of the frequency. The frequency difference you had notice is not relevant, it is very low, and most of the times higher frequency means higher operations per sec, so in theory that 4.39 you are getting in W10 should be better. For that reason I stick with my background utilization usage theory. One thing you can try if you have multiple monitors, is to detach them when you are gaming, it will improve cpu usage. You can also try to overclock, but I don't know your hardware configuration and your cooler, so I cannot say anything more about that.

Comment: No. Both windows are installed with a difference of one day. Yes, on Win10, performance is slightly better, but because of this, it creates processor overload.

Comment: If you use VSync, or you limit framerate to something lower that what you are getting, you will experience lower cpu usage, but at the cost of getting input lag and less FPS.

Comment: I know it. On win10 I get a “strange” input delay at 120 fps, and on win 8.1 I don’t get such a delay even in unlimited FPS.

Comment: With VSync ON or OFF? And what is your monitor refresh rate?

Comment: VSync OFF ofc, it is not playable.

Comment: I don't play fortnite a lot, but for me VSync helped in avoiding impossible lag spikes at 1080p, try enabling it. I have a R9 3900x @4.2 and a 2080 Super. I know you are gonna get input lag, but you know, pick your poison. At least your cpu utilization will be normal.

Comment: And about your question, usually older OS are easier to run (but less optimized), that's all.

Comment: My question is rather how to make Windows use the CPU not by 100%, but by 99% but still maintain overclocking.

Comment: Maybe you can try lowering the process priority under Task Manager > Details

Comment: Anyway, my task manager shows 4.18Ghz, when cpu-z and HWINFO64 show 4.199Ghz and 4.200Ghz, so take in consideration that there are different reads